# Explanation of the parameters of knn.score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

In the code below (last line) it is used the X_test and y_test which according to the docs:

> Returns the mean accuracy on the given *test data* and *label*

The question is what exactly is calculated since `X_test` has the data from the test data and the `y_test` has the labels for these data.

It would make sense to check the predicted labels vs the actual labels.

Can you tell me how the first scenario works in the last line?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'], 
random_state=0)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Test set score: {:.2f}".format(knn.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.score):

```
Parameters: 

X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features)

    Test samples.
y : array-like, shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)

    True labels for X.
sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples], optional

    Sample weights.

Returns:    

score : float

    Mean accuracy of self.predict(X) wrt. y.
```

What happens in the back?
It is predicting: `knn.predict(X_test)` and then using these values to calculate the mean accuracy between `knn.predict(X_test)` and  `y_test`.
You should get the same output with [sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_predict = knn.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
```